# How to pass content of LinkedList between classes of same package

Tags: java

I'm developing a console java program for an auctioning system. In the main class (auctioningSystem) I hard-coded a LinkedList of users:

```
//Linked lists declared to store, auctions, users, and items
private static LinkedList<User> users = new LinkedList<User>(); 



public AuctioningSystem(){

}

public static void main(String[] args) {

    //inserting users in the system, buyers and sellers (hard-coded)
    users.add(new User("Abel", "pw123", "Seller"));
    users.add(new User("Kamil", "pw123", "Seller"));
    users.add(new User("Rob", "pw123", "Seller"));
```

...

Now, i want to call a method of the class User (from the system class) that I'm using to check the username and password (passing LinkedList, username and password as arguments)

The question is How can I do to compare the username and password indroduced by keypad with usernames and passwords in the LinkedList?

As when I print the content of the linked list it shows:

```
    Iterator<User> iterator = users.iterator();
    while(iterator.hasNext())
    {
        System.out.println(iterator.next());
    }
```

Content:

User@72ea2f77

User@33c7353a

User@681a9515

This is the method of the class User to validate user Login:

```
public static boolean validateLogIn( LinkedList<User> users, String username, String password){

Iterator<User> spin = users.iterator();
    while (spin.hasNext()){
        System.out.println("I'm roling");
        if(username.equals(users.contains(username)) && password.equals(users.contains(password))){
            System.out.println("BINGO!");
            return userLogedIn=true;
        }
        else{
            return false;
        }
    }
```

This is my initial idea but it doesn't work, I think I'm not accessing in the right way to the data in the linkedlist or something like that but don't know how to fix it :(
Any ideas? thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to extract user from the iterator using [Iterator.next()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Iterator.html#next()).

Sample code:

```
public static boolean validateLogIn( LinkedList<User> users, 
    String username, String password) {

    Iterator<User> spin = users.iterator();
    while (spin.hasNext()) {
        User user = spin.next();
        System.out.println("I'm roling");
        if(username.equals(user.getUsername()) && 
           password.equals(user.getPassword())) {
            System.out.println("BINGO!");
            return userLogedIn=true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

I think it would be better to move validation inside `User` class. Like:

```
public boolean validate(String username, String password) {
    if (!password.equals(this.password))
        return false;
    if (!username.equals(this.username))
        return false;
    return true;
}
```

And modify `validateLogIn` method like following will make your code more readable:

```
public static boolean validateLogIn(LinkedList<User> users,
        String username, String password) {

    Iterator<User> spin = users.iterator();
    while (spin.hasNext()) {
        User user = spin.next();
        System.out.println("I'm roling");
        if (user.validate(username, password)) {
            System.out.println("BINGO!");
            return userLogedIn = true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }

    return false;
}
```

Comment: I think this is the closer approach but for some reason still not matching the username and password in the if statement, therefore fails to log-in. I'll keep squeezing my brain a bit more..

Comment: could the reason be that the string I'm comparing is being compared agains a hex value? For example the value that I'm printing User@72ea2f77 and not against the proper values inside the linkedList?

Comment: I've sorted it out, the problem was in the setters and getters... ;)

Answer (score 1):

It seems that the main question is already resolved; but to give some further advice: the reason that the output looks like "User@72ea2f77" is caused by the fact that the "default" implementation for toString() (inherited from java.lang.Object) is used. You might want to override toString() in order to produce a more helpful output, for example:

```
@Override
public String toString() {
     return "Name: " + getName();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use an advanced for loop, and check each user object against the username and password

```
 for (User user: users)
        if(username.equals(user.getName()) && password.equals(user.getPassword())){
            System.out.println("BINGO!");
            return userLogedIn=true;
        }
        else{
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```